# High voltage (70V) amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, motor, high-voltage, synchro

I need to generate a *400Hz 26V rms* signal with at least 200mA drive capability. 26V rms means 72.8V p-p is required. It is to drive the rotor winding on a synchro system.

I was planning to use 2 x OPA552 op amps single supply in BTL configuration until I discovered that I need to ground one side of the output. So now I think I need to use a dual supply configuration, but the OPA552 runs out of voltage (max +/-30V) and probably power dissipation too.

I have the 400Hz sine wave signal at 5V p-p at 0 & 180 deg (for BTL inputs).

Two questions:

- any suggestions for suitable op amps or other circuit configurations I could use?  Possibly an op-amp driving some transistors or MOSFETs?
- what is the best way to get my 0-5V input signal (DC offset of 2.5V) to the correct level to feed a dual supply amp?  I could obviously use a capacitor but I would prefer to avoid any phase shift.

TIA

Comment: Well, a discrete [voltage booster stage](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa600b/snoa600b.pdf) is always feasible. Asking for a precise opamp to use... will probably get your question closed as a shopping question. Apex Microtechnology makes higher voltage opamps but they're [hybrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_integrated_circuit), not monolithic ICs, so they cost a lot.

Comment: Also since you're asking about motor drive... there might exist more specialized solutions; it might help to tag your question accordingly. I've paralleled OPA551s [to get higher currents], but for driving high-power ultrasonic transducers, not for motors.

Comment: Thanks. The app note looks very useful. I have added the 'motor' tag. Yes I saw the Apex offerings and my eyes are still watering :-)

Comment: So a synchro seems to need only a pure sine wave to drive. I'm not sure why you want to use an amplifier for this since you're not going to change the shape of the wave. Cant you just use a transformer? I'm assuming you have a 400Hz AC power source, i.e., this is on an aircraft or something like that. Even if you don't have that a sine oscillator is cheaper to make than a high-linearity amp.

Comment: 400Hz puts the frequency squarely in the realms of audio power amps. 26v *200mA = about 5 watts, say 20 watts once you've had the peak music versus continuous debate. The impedance of your load is 26/0.2 = 130 ohms, a 1:5 step up transformer driving it would bring your input impedance down into the 4-8 ohm range beloved of audio amps. A 50Hz transformer would be more lossy at this frequency than at 50, but may still work well enough. Some iron toriodal transfromers are speced at 400Hz, for exactly this sort of use!

Comment: @user44635: that sounds like a very good answer. I suggest you copy it to an answer box. Audio amps are cheap (much cheaper than OPAs) because they are mass produced in much larger quantities. I've abused that fact on occasion by using an LM1875 instead of a LM675 for example.

Comment: Why didn't you use driver ICs. Their control pins are TTL range and output pins are as Top as 600V. Such of them is NCP5106 : http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP5106-D.PDF

Comment: Audio amps have capacitors at input stage, therefore you will get the phase shift. Perhaps using D-class amplifier without input filtering.

Comment: I guess I could just use a transformer - hadn't actually considered that. I will check out these driver ICs - the idea of using PWM to driver MOSFET switches sounds like a good way to go. Generating the PWM isn't too hard. Using Op amps is definitely going to cause a thermal problem.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use driver chips for running high voltage devices. On of these chips are [NCP5106-D](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP5106-D.PDF) that its input voltage is 3.3-5 volt and output voltage up to 600V . It's used as a Mosfet driver too, that can drive your Load.

[image]

For acquiring a dual supply from a single supply there are lots of chips such as 7805 and 7905 used together. Although if you run a current spike load such as motors, it's better to isolate ground from both sides. In this case you can use [MinMax Voltage Isolators](http://minmax.com.tw/) such as MAU3000 series.

Comment: These are on/off digital devices - not analogue amplifiers - you wont get a sine wave out of them.

Comment: @Icy Exactly. These are digital devices. In case of controlling speed of a Motor you can use a PWM wave for controlling your motor. Indeed by use of a 3rd order RLC filter you can have a semi-sine wave in output of your PWM wave for other not precises applications.

Comment: but the OP has a sine wave and wants a sine wave (for a synchronous motor) - he hasn't got a PWM source, and you haven't shown the 3rd order filter.

Comment: @HOPE To get my output ground referenced (ie positive and negative with respect to ground) I need dual supplies. From what I understand these driver chips don't support that. Or do they? Is that what you are suggesting with the MinMax Isolators?

Comment: Minmax Isolators have isolated GND. There are dual form of them such as : MAU1015: http://minmax.com.tw/upfiles/all_/en_quickfiles_caty01345682243.PDF 
These chips benefit is their GROUND pin isolation. If don't see this necessary just use 7805/7905 configuration for example.

Comment: @HOPE I am not sure where I need to put these isolators and whether this gate driver can be used to drive dual supply MOSFETs. Say I have my dual supply (+/- 40V), the MOSFETs are strung between the +40V and -40V rails with the output coming off the center point through an LC filter. NCP5106A will not drive the low side MOSFET, unless I shift it down to have the -40V rail as its ground reference. Then I have to supply the VCC to the driver chip wrt the -40V rail - maybe this is where you are suggesting I use the isolated converter? There is also the issue of level shifting the input signals?